# Discontinuar lineado de un gráfico para n niveles de un factor utilizando ggplot

Tags: r

Tengo un código con el que grafico unos datos similares a los del ejemplo mínimo que comparto.

Como puede observarse la variable z contiene 4 condiciones: "H C R", "I C R", "H C W" e "I C W".

Actualmente, al graficar, cada condición aparece de un color diferente según la paleta de colores "Spectral".

**Objetivo**

Me gustaría conseguir lo siguiente:

1. Que la línea de condición "H C" apareciera en el color anaranjado que utiliza la paleta "Spectral".
2. Que la línea de condición "I C" apareciera en el color verde oscuro que utiliza la paleta "Spectral".
3. Que la línea de condición "R" apareciera continua.
4. Que la línea de la condición "W" apareciera discontínua.

Por motivos de organización, sería preferible separar en la leyenda dos grupos de títulos de leyenda: *Condición* para "H C" e "I C" y *Modelo* para "R" y "W".

Mis intentos hasta ahora han pasado por intentar hacer un separación de los niveles de z y después utilizar linetype para cambiar el estilo de línea. Pero tengo problemas porque el código opera datos dentro de una tubería.

Agradezco sugerencias.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
tribble(    ~y,    ~cb,   ~z,    ~x,
            1     , 0,   "H C R"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "H C R"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "I C R"    ,1,
            3     , 1,   "I C R"    ,1,
            1.5   , 0,   "H C W"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "H C W"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "I C W"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "I C W"    ,1,
            3     , 0,   "H C R"    ,2,
            3     , 1,   "H C R"    ,2,
            0.5   , 0,   "I C R"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "I C R"    ,2,
            2     , 0,   "H C W"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "H C W"    ,2,
            1     , 0,   "I C W"    ,2,
            1     , 1,   "I C W"    ,2)-> datos
datos %>%
  group_by(x, z, cb) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = sd(y),                            
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),       
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = media, color = z)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = z), size=0.5) +                      
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = intervalo_sup,               
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),
                width=0.3) + 
  labs(x = "x", y = "y", color = "Condition") +
  scale_color_brewer(type='div', palette="Spectral") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,7, by=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  facet_wrap(~cb)
```

Comment: ¿Los datos tiene que permanecer dentro de la tubería o es aceptable una solución salvando los datos antes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la siguiente aproximación se guardan los datos antes de hacer el gráfico,se usan filtros dentro de los `geom` para dar distintos estilos a los distintos niveles de `z` y por ultimo se agregan colores manuales con `library(RColorBrewer)` y `scale_color_manual`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
tribble(    ~y,    ~cb,   ~z,    ~x,
            1     , 0,   "H C R"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "H C R"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "I C R"    ,1,
            3     , 1,   "I C R"    ,1,
            1.5   , 0,   "H C W"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "H C W"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "I C W"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "I C W"    ,1,
            3     , 0,   "H C R"    ,2,
            3     , 1,   "H C R"    ,2,
            0.5   , 0,   "I C R"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "I C R"    ,2,
            2     , 0,   "H C W"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "H C W"    ,2,
            1     , 0,   "I C W"    ,2,
            1     , 1,   "I C W"    ,2)-> datos

#Preparamos los datos
aux<-datos %>%
  group_by(x, z, cb) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = rnorm(1),#Tube que simular la desvio sd() arrojaba NaN                         
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),       
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) #%>%

#Seleccionamos los colores
library(RColorBrewer)
display.brewer.pal(11,name = "Spectral")  
brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")
# Que la línea de condición "H C" apareciera en el color anaranjado que utiliza la paleta "Spectral".
# Que la línea de condición "I C" apareciera en el color verde oscuro que utiliza la paleta "Spectral".
colores<-brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")[c(3,3,9,9)]




  ggplot() +
    # Que la línea de la condición "W" apareciera discontínua.
  geom_line(data=aux%>%filter(grepl("W",z)),
            aes(x = x, y = media, color = z,group = z),
            size=0.5,
            linetype = "dashed") +                      
  geom_errorbar(data=aux%>%filter(grepl("W",z)),aes(x = x, color = z,
                              ymax = intervalo_sup,               
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),
                width=0.3) + 
    # Que la línea de condición "R" apareciera continua.
    geom_line(data=aux%>%filter(!grepl("W",z)),
              aes(x = x, y = media, color = z,group = z),
              size=0.5) +                      
    geom_errorbar(data=aux%>%filter(!grepl("W",z)),
                  aes(x = x, color = z,
                                ymax = intervalo_sup,               
                                ymin = intervalo_inf),
                  width=0.3)+
  labs(x = "x", y = "y", color = "Condition") +
    #Agregamos los colores que seleccionamos antes
  scale_color_manual(values=colores) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,7, by=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  facet_wrap(~cb)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, muy buena. Esto es parecido a lo que buscaba por otro método. No obstante, me queda solucionar la leyenda en dos bloques tal y como proponía en la pregunta. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: @pyring no he podido revisar el problema estos días y de pronto no se me viene alguna idea de como resolverlo.